# How can I select transparent parts of a raster image I placed in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, selections

I have an image. it is an object with a transparent background. how can I make the selection around the object itself and not the square with the object and transparency. I exported this image from gimp and opened it in illustrator. I have tried everything I can think of but I am not very good with adobe illsutrator. I'm currently using the CC version.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Importing an image into Illustrator imports everything, transparent pixels included. Illustrator doesn't understand that there might be different components in a bitmap image, it just renders the image object as a whole.

Please explain what you are trying to achieve and we will be able to suggest a process.

Comment: i want make the selection around the object in my picture, not the whole picture. the only thing that is not transparent is what i want to select. So i basically want to delete the transparent pixels

Comment: Illustrator does not operate on pixels. Trace it or export a path from gimp.

Comment: how do i trace it?

Comment: But... Why do you need to select thoose? If it a transpareng png, put whatever you need under the png.

Answer (score 1):

As [Joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) said, you are best with tracing your file, you can do this as follows.

Lock you layer and then create a new layer above it.

[image: 1]

Use the pen tool (P), holding shift to draw straight lines and clicking and dragging to create a curve. You can then use the Direct Selection tool to select any point you have created and may need to edit.

[image: 2]
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

All bitmap images are rectangles.  There's no way to import just the opaque pixels. You'll always have a rectangular bounding box around the image.

You might be able to achieve something close to what you want with a clipping mask.

For instance if you have a photo of a basketball on the ground. Import that into illustrator (file-->place).  Draw a circle on top of the basketball and make it the precise size of the basketball.  Select both photo and circle and select Object-->Clipping Mask--Make.

You now have a round basketball object.  The square shape is still there, but hidden by the clipping mask.